# Unable to delombok: InvocationTargetException

Tags: maven, lombok

Unable to delombok: InvocationTargetException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: Class com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCImport does not have member field 'com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree qualid' (this is the error on terminal)

I am building code but getting this error on running "mvn clean install" I was using jdk 21 before but now I shifted to jdk 17 (since some posts online were saying it's incompatible with 21) but I am still getting the same error,  "lombok:1.18.20.0:delombok (default)" this is show on the terminal followed by BUILD FAILURE, help to build the code would be really appreciated as I have been stuck on this error for a long time now.

Thanking in advance

Comment: You should upgrade the lombok version to most recent one https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok/versions (1.8.30)...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are using the `lombok-maven-plugin` to perform the delombok task during a Maven build. That is a third-party plugin not maintained by the lombok team, and it has not been updated for several lombok versions. The latest plugin version 1.18.20.0 uses lombok 1.18.20, which does *not* work for JDK 17 or JDK 21.

However, you can easily instruct `lombok-maven-plugin` to use a newer lombok version via `pom.xml`:

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.18.20.0</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        <version>1.18.30</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: This was my solution...Even when using a modern version of spring/boot the maven plugin for (de)lomboking is using an older version. Ensure you use lombok version >=1.18.30